# Unsafe operation in my first JavaFX application

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2

Please have a look at my first JavaFX application code

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class HelloWorld2 extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("Hello World");

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Hello");
        btn.setOnAction(new Action());

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(btn);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300,250));
        stage.show();
    }

    private class Action implements EventHandler
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event arg0) 
        {
            System.out.println("JavaFX World");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I am getting "Unsafe Operation" warning when I run this. Application runs without any exceptions. I believe unsafe thing is coming because I have to put  keyword in some place, but I don't know where. Please help!

Comment: @PeterLawrey: haha, ya, you know, printing mistake ;) LOL :D

Thanks Uluk for correcting it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to specify the type of Event

```
private class Action implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        System.out.println("JavaFX World");
    }
}
```